# Discord Bot, problem while mentioning discord @users

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord, mention

[The line where i want to mention the user with @](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFhjU.png)

[first part of the code[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFhjU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJArx.png)
[2nn part of the code after the mention i want to apply[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJArx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6IrI.png)
I am developing a discord bot and I want the bot to mention the user that applied the command. I can show you more of the code. It is a bit complicated. I tried many times Mention.user and some other common answers but nothing happened.

ps. Edit: i provided 2 more images with the code if thats enough :)

Comment: Please post the code in your question, rather than in an image.

Comment: What discordAPI are you using? Also, no libraries can send "@User" to mention someone, in discord.py you have to send userObject.mention(), in discord.js you have to send the user object. We cant help without knowing the language

Comment: Ok thank for answering me, i am using discord.js (Javascript) . So what do i have to do ? @TomMartin .You said that i have to send the user object ? I am not that familiar with javascript, what do you mean by that ? Thank u in advance, i appreciate both help :)

Comment: @BillPapadodemas Is the 'line' where you want to mention the user inside a `client.on("message"`, or `bot.on("message"`? If it is, you will be able to do `message.channel.send(\`${message.member.user} You are being mentioned!\`)` I will add some more info in an answer

Comment: Also, NEVER post images of code. Please, for my sanity.

Comment: It is also fine to send `message.author`, as it returns the same object as `message.member.user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to [the discord.js site](http://discord.js.org) and click on `Documentation` in the top right, it will bring you to a page where you can learn about all of the objects in the discord.js api.

In your `client.on("message")`, message is defined, it is a message object, so to find that in the docs scroll down and look on the left side for `Message`, and click on it. You can now see all of the attributes that class has, it has an `author`, which the docs say is of type `User`. I have told you if you send a user object in a message, it will mention the user. So, send `message.author` and tada!

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Martin said, your current format is not compatible with Discord's API. There are a couple issues with this code.
    First off, unless you want unexpected results out of your for loops you should change to the ES6 standard of let to maintain lexical scope to only that block.
    Second in Javascript (JS) everything is an object. So essentially you must choose the method that returns the user object then either immediately use it or store it. How you do that is up to you, although, here is an [example](https://discordjs.guide/#/popular-topics/common-questions) from discord.js themselves.
    [Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) is a link to the users method of the [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/) documentation. This will return a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) (explanation of data structure) of all the User objects mapped by id. Hopefully this helped and good luck with your bot!

Comment: Thank u for your advice, i will try my best but i really find it difficult to write on js. I am familiar only with Java (begginer) .

Comment: Maybe try going through a beginner course on the likes of code academy then, it may help bridge some of the abstractions that JavaScript puts in place that Java doesn't or vice versa. Another great resource is the "You don't know JS" book series. Give those a once over you should be a JS programmer in no time.